# How to change background color in paragraph depending on the value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change background color with check if `{this.state.list[0].main.temp}` > 10 background color of this paragraph to be yellow ..

Code:

```
const getBackground = (temperature) => {
    if(temperature > 30) return "red"
    if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
    if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"
    return "transparent"
  }
  
  renderForecast1 = () => {
    if (this.state && this.state.list) {
      const list = this.state.list[0];
      return (
        <p style={{ backgroundColor: getBackground(list.main.temp) }}>
          Date: {list.dt_txt}h <br />
          Temperature: {list.main.temp} °C <br />
          Chance of precipitation: {list.pop} mm <br />
          Wind Speed: {Math.round(list.wind.speed, 1) * 3.6} km/h <br />
          Pressure: {list.main.pressure} hPa <br />
          Humidity: {list.main.humidity} %
        </p>
      );
    }
  };
```

I receive error:

```
 SyntaxError: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\weather\weather\src\App.js: Unexpected token (86:8)

  84 |   };
  85 |
> 86 |   const getBackground = (temperature) => {
     |         ^
  87 |     if(temperature > 30) return "red"
  88 |     if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
  89 |     if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"
```

How to do that ?

I use `<div className='row' style={{ fontSize: "15px" }}>{this.renderForecast1()}</div>` to display the data..

Comment: how are you using `renderForecast1`?

Comment: What's the code immediately preceding `getBackground`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a valid Javascript syntax, you writing a function as part of class members. Remove the `const` and call it through `this.`

```
getBackground = (temperature) => {
  ...
};

renderForecast1 = () => {
  if (this.state && this.state.list) {
    const list = this.state.list[0];
    return (
      <p style={{ backgroundColor: this.getBackground(list.main.temp) }}>
        ...
      </p>
    );
  }
};
```